# Ajax Error in IE 11: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x8, Not enough storage is available to process this command

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

an AJAX call I'm running is generating the following error in the console of Internet Explorer 11 (but works fine in Chrome).

> SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x8, Not enough storage is available to process this command.

The code being used is as follows:

```
    $.ajax({
     url: '../../../../ajax/create',
     dataType: 'json',
     cache: false,
     success: function(result) { alert('success'); }
    });
```

This error goes away if I reduce the amount of work run at:

> ajax/create

My goal is to have IE 11 handle the call without being forced to reduce the processes.  It takes around 25 seconds to run (on Chrome).  I've raised the PHP memory limit and timeout limit on "../ajax/create" with no luck (dedicated server so no limitations).

Any ideas?

Comment: 25 seconds seems like a really long wait... is there no way to instead return immediately from the request, then poll on an interval to see when it is finished?

Comment: Sounds like IE11 might have a max execution time for AJAX requests?

Comment: Related? **http://support.microsoft.com/kb/106167**

Comment: How much data/json is the `ajax/create` response returning?

Comment: The response is returning minimal AJAX, around 100 - 200 characters.

Comment: @MonkeyZues It's not a Windows server so I don't think that's it, and I'd expect a "Script unresponsive" warning if it's a max execution time.

Comment: @Kevin B - This might work, although I still wouldn't be able to tell if it completed successfully or not.  Would the file run completely even if the AJAX didn't return successfully?  If so, perhaps watching for any response, successful or not, would work.  Thoughts?

Comment: My idea would rely on having the php script send an http request with timeout of 0 to the script that actually does the work, then returning success. You would then send additional ajax requests to yet another script that checks the status of the original request to see if it is done, and whether or or not it was successful. Of course, if you don't care whether or not it was successful or even if it is complete, you don't have to send any of the additional requests. The Goal is the user can continue working on your web app while the long process is happening in the background.

Comment: @KevinB B I like it, thanks for the idea.  It seems like a workaround but perhaps a better solution than the beginning idea.  A basic question but related - if I start an AJAX call and then navigate away, that process will continue on the server, as once it begins it is no longer dependent on the client, correct?

Comment: As long as the request portion completes, yes.

Comment: I had this same error in ASP.NET MVC and was finally able to get around it.  I was generating a couple of hundred embedded forms in the page with each having @Html.AntiForgeryToken() .  I believe this results in creating a cookie on the client side.  Potentially IE was running out of space for the cookies (or something, who knows with IE).  Removed it and my problem went away.